# .htaccess regex redirects - how to REMOVE a keyword?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Situation: many pages on a website were "moved up a level", e.g.

`www.example.com/all-widgets/red-widgets/widget001`
is now
`www.example.com/red-widgets/widget001`

Problem: many outdated links that include the now-defunct /all-widgets/ category.

What's the regex syntax to **remove** a keyword from a URL?

In other words, "If any incoming URL includes **this keyword**, remove **only** this keyword but leave the rest of the URL intact".

---

Follow-up: there may be situations where the keyword must be an exact, 1-time match, because it might occur elsewhere in the URL.

In other words, it's a possibility that an incoming URL like this might exist:

`www.example.com/all-widgets/red-widgets/widget074-compatible-with-all-widgets`

I need to remove only the **1st** occurrence of "all-widgets" (to fix the category-migration issue), but leave the rest intact (so it doesn't break the actual product/blogpost URL).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
RewriteRule /all-widgets/(.*) $1 [L, R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will separate the leading `all-widgets` from your url `^all-widgets/(.+)$`. You can then add your rewrite rule based on how you want to route the rest: 
eg,

```
RewriteRule ^all-widgets/(.+)$ $1
```

Comment: Request for clarification: so, the syntax `RewriteRule ^(all-widgets\/)(.+)$ $2` will rewrite `www.example.com/all-widgets/red-widgets/widget001` to `www.example.com/red-widgets/widget001` ? Or do I need to add anything else?

Comment: I updated my answer a little. Please check. Yes, it will rewrite your URL like you mentioned. If, then new path exists in your web server you should not add anything else. However, it wont redirect to the new URL, so your users will still see the old URL.

Comment: It won't work for cases when URL is not starting with `all-widgets`.

Comment: If URL does not start with `all-widgets` the regex wont match and the original URL will pass, which should work regardless as per the issue description. (unless the URL is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to remove **first instance** of `all-widgets` from anywhere in URL. It also caters to cases when URL is not starting with `all-widgets`.

```
RewriteEngin On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(?:|(.*?)/)all-widgets(/.*|)$ $1$2 [L,R=301,NE,NC]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fKlXRB/3)